# How to define that mock method gets invoked zero times

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I'm trying to test the following method:

```
//AuthenticationMiddleware Middleware which handles all of the authentication.
func AuthenticationMiddleware(context context.ContextIntf, w web.ResponseWriter, r *web.Request, next web.NextMiddlewareFunc) {
    //Check if url is one that doesn't need authorization. If not than send them to the login page.
    for _, url := range AuthMWInstance.GetInfo().nonAuthURLs {
        if url.Method == r.Method && strings.Contains(r.URL.Path, url.DomainName) {
            next(w, r)
            return
        }
    }

    if errSt := CheckForAuthorization(context, r, w); errSt != nil {
        responses.Write(w, responses.Unauthorized(*errSt))
        return
    }
    defer context.GetInfo().Session.SessionRelease(w)
    next(w, r)
}
```

In this case, there's a `SessionRelease` that gets invoked iff `r` contains a URL that requires authorization, and that authorization was successful.

It may be important to know that :

```
type MiddlewareSt struct {
    //NonAuthUrls URLs that can be accessed without a token.
    nonAuthURLs []url.URLSt
}

type MiddlewareIntf interface {
    GetInfo() *MiddlewareSt
    CheckTokenAndSetSession(context context.ContextIntf, r *web.Request, w web.ResponseWriter,
        token string, scope string, remoteAddr string) *errors.ErrorSt
}

var AuthMWInstance MiddlewareIntf
```

and that `CheckForAuthorization`'s return value ultimately relies upon `AuthMWInstance`

**My Test Strategy**

- Create a stub middleware instance to initialize `AuthMWInstance` to, that simply returns `nil` for `CheckTokenAndSetSession` (with the session setting abstracted out, of course, to the creation of the stub object itself, which has the `Session`), and a `MiddlewareSt` full of fake `nonAuthURLs` for `GetInfo()`
- Create a mock [`session.Store`](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/session#Store) that, for all tests except the Sanity Test, expects zero calls to `SessionRelease`.

*It's probably worth noting (but assumed) that I'm using [testify](http://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock),[mockery](https://godoc.org/github.com/vektra/mockery) libraries for the mocking and the assertion stuff.*

**The test**

Is implemented thus:

```
func TestAuthenticationMiddleware(t *testing.T) {
    // bring in the errors
    sdkTesting.InitErrors()
    // create/set up the test doubles
    // mock session
    sessionMock := new(testing_mock.MockStore)
    // temporarily set AuthMWInstance to a stub
    instance := AuthMWInstance
    AuthMWInstance = &StubMiddlewareInstance{
        Session: sessionMock,
    }
    // AuthMWInstance.Session
    defer func() { AuthMWInstance = instance }()
    // fake ResponseWriter
    w := new(StubResponseWriter)
    // fake web requests
    requestWithoutAuth := new(web.Request)
    requestWithoutAuth.Request = httptest.NewRequest("GET",
        "http://example.com/logout",
        nil,
    )

    // do tests here
    t.Run("AuthorizationNotRequired", func(t *testing.T) {
        // place expectations on sessionMock, namely that it does
        //  **not** invoke `SessionRelease`
        sessionMock.On("SessionRelease", w).
            Times(0)

        AuthenticationMiddleware(new(context.Context),
            w,
            requestWithoutAuth,
            web.NextMiddlewareFunc(func(web.ResponseWriter, *web.Request) {}))

        sessionMock.AssertExpectations(t)
    })

}
```

**Runtime behavior**

The following false fail happens: [image]. It's literally as if, instead of doing:

```
sessionMock.On("SessionRelease", w).
            Times(0)
```

, I was like:

```
sessionMock.On("SessionRelease", w).
            Once()
```

**NOTE** `session.Store.SessionRelease` does not return anything, hence why I didn't even bother using `Return()`.

**Am I asserting that it is to be called exactly zero times right?**

Comment: Not an exact answer to your question, so I'll post it as comment.. But it looks like it'd be pretty easy to sidestep the problem and use a custom test double that simply raises an error in its `SessionRelease` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a bit silly for this.

The problem was that I was bothering with

```
sessionMock.AssertExpectations(t)
```

when I could have simply said

```
sessionMock.AssertNotCalled(t, "SessionRelease", w)
```

(Documentation on that method [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#Mock.AssertNotCalled))

Doing the latter resolved the issue, and did exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does `AssertNotCalled` distinguish between `SessionRelease` or `context.GetInfo().Session.SessionRelease` (as in complete invocation) ?